# How to make bootstrap navbar activate on hover, and do something else on when clicked?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am using the bootstrap 4 navigation bar, but I made a modification to trigger the dropdown via hover instead of a click. I changed the pointer-events property because when you click the dropdown button, the dropdown becomes sticky.

However, I want to be able to make the dropdown button clickable too so that when I click on it, it takes me to a link on the website. If I change the pointer-events to 'true', it works fine, but then the dropdown becomes sticky. It stays open until I click somewhere else in the website.

Here's my code.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data- 
     toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
     Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>    
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS Style

```
.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown>.dropdown-toggle:active {
  /*Without this, clicking will make it sticky*/
    pointer-events: none;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not the solution but I think your final `</div>` should be `</ul>`.  Please include enough code to reproduce the problem.  Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Play with the code in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/7qao5t4m/1/).

Comment: Here's the complete code https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/mdbootstrap/949116

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with this JS code:

```
 $('.dropdown').on('click', function(){
        location.href='www.example.com';
    });
```

Comment: I tried this but I'd have to make the pointer-events to true for it work. Now, it works but the dropdown becomes sticky again

Answer (score 0):

With a quick search of `bootstrap navbar hover dropdown` the first result gave the answer you are looking for.  PLEASE RESEARCH BEFORE POSTING A QUESTION!

Source: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-make-the-bootstrap-navbar-dropdown-work-on-hover--cms-33840

jQuery:

```
const $dropdown = $(".dropdown");
const $dropdownToggle = $(".dropdown-toggle");
const $dropdownMenu = $(".dropdown-menu");
const showClass = "show";

$(window).on("load resize", function() {
  if (this.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)").matches) {
    $dropdown.hover(
      function() {
        const $this = $(this);
        $this.addClass(showClass);
        $this.find($dropdownToggle).attr("aria-expanded", "true");
        $this.find($dropdownMenu).addClass(showClass);
      },
      function() {
        const $this = $(this);
        $this.removeClass(showClass);
        $this.find($dropdownToggle).attr("aria-expanded", "false");
        $this.find($dropdownMenu).removeClass(showClass);
      }
    );
  } else {
    $dropdown.off("mouseenter mouseleave");
  }
});
```